# Restrictions for in-app purchasing across multiple platforms

Tags: ios, cross-platform, mac-app-store

I am developing a native iOS app that involves in-app purchasing of consumable digital goods. I am aware of the restrictions on building apps that try to circumvent the 30% commission that Apple takes on in-app purchases, but I wasn't sure how this works for cross-platform applications.

For example, let's say I have a new game called FarmLand, which is available on iOS, Android, as well as on the web. In order to advance the story you need to purchase FarmBucks within the game. If someone has an account which they can log into on all three platforms, what's stopping them from going on the website, paying $X to load their account with a certain amount of FarmBucks, then logging into their account on the app and spending them? (in this case bypassing the 30% in-app purchasing fee)

Any insight on this would be appreciated- thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The only way that apple takes money from you is if they buy it while in your app. This means that:

- Buying currency on a website, *launched outside of your app*
- Buying currency on another phone then using the same account on iOS

will not be subject to the 30% fee.